# How to read text from a file into an array and then print the whole array out

Tags: arrays, c, list, file, char

Okay! Pretty new to this stuff!

This is part of a bit bigger task and the problem I have now is that I have a list of names (100 names) inside a text file. They're written like this:

Sam (enter) Oliver (enter) Paul (enter) --- and so on.

So every name is on its own row. I'm trying to read this into a char array which I'll then print out to check if it works. I'll have to do something else to it afterward but I want to figure that out later.
Here's my code right now: (File names etc. are in Finnish so don't bother with that! :D)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *tiedosto;
    char *array[100];
    char nimi[] = "names.txt";

    tiedosto = fopen(nimi, "r");

    if (tiedosto == NULL) {
        printf("Tiedostoa ei voida avata");
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        fscanf(tiedosto, "%s", &array[i]);
    }
    fclose(tiedosto);

    printf("Tulostetaan taulukko \n");
    // printf("%s \n",array);

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%s \n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'char * array[100];' ok, but you have to mallocate, or similar, each string before loading its address into that array.  You are currently blowing the strings, almost, on top of each other, into the pointer array:(

Comment: Okay... I've used malloc on a course before but not sure how that works. Could you explain so i understand?

Comment: There is a 'malloc' tag with lots of examples.  Also 'man malloc' on *nix or Google 'malloc'.

Comment: https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/main/c/read-txt-into-array.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got several errors in the code:

1. In this line:

   ```
   fscanf(tiedosto, "%s", &array[i]);
   ```

   You don't need to use an ampersand sign here. It's because the `array` is already the type of `char*[]` – in such situations, you must avoid passing `char**`.
2. In the following code segment:

   ```
   if (tiedosto == NULL) {
       printf("Tiedostoa ei voida avata");
       return; // ***
   }
   ```

   The return type of the `main()` is an integer, so it must pass something non-void. Any non-zero return code would indicate an unsuccessful program closure.
3. In this declaration:

   ```
   char *array[100];
   ```

   The `array` is using a pointer alongside the array too. Thus this must be initialized using the `malloc()` function properly so that you don't hit with a segfault.

   In case you don't want to get messed up of allocating memory, etc. try switching to two-dimensional array declaration:

   ```
   char array[TOTAL_ENTRIES][PER_NAME_LEN];
   ```

---

I have described the 2-D array approach to avoid code complexity (read comments for explanation):

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Some global macros throughout this program
#define MAX_USERS    100
#define MAX_STRLEN   64

#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1

int main(void) {
    const char *file_name = "names.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    char name_list[MAX_USERS][MAX_STRLEN];
    int count = 0;

    // Using perror() is the best option here
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Reading the file contents and saving that into 2-D array
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", name_list[count++]) != EOF)
        ;

    // Displaying the saved array contents        
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", name_list[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

In this program, the number of lines in the `names.txt` file can be anything lesser than or equal to 100.

Comment: THANKS! Was getting desperate trying to understand memory allocation but i got it to work now! Changing to a 2D-array worked. Don't know why i didn't think about that.

Comment: @OliverHotakainen you're welcome. Actually, I'm still working on its code development.